# Laravel 5.4 image resizing issue

Tags: laravel-5.4, intervention

I have a problem on resizing image in laravel 5.4

I am using the following code to resize image:

```
    $sample_front_image = $request->file('sample_front_image');
    $input['sample_front_image'] = $sample_front_image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image_resize = Image::make($sample_front_image->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize(120, 120);
    $image_resize->save(public_path($thumbnail_dir, $input['sample_front_image']));
```

But I am getting the following error showing below:
[image]

It seems that above code is working fine for previous laravel versions but is not working on 5.4 version. Any Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Intervention is not able to find the image you are passing it for resizing. You are providing temporary image path to the Image::make() instead of the actual path.

So first you have to upload the image using store() to somewhere and then need to provide that image full path to the Image::make().

Hope this helps.